# Is it possible to override the property setter of a super class without needing to redefine the property

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, properties, getter-setter

I have classes, sharing the same property with the same getters, but different setters. As a simple, useless example, something like:

```
class Spam():
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo):
        self.bar = foo


class Eggs(Spam):
    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo):
        self.bar = ' '.join(['Egg\'s foo:', foo])
```

Trying to run this module however throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Eggs(Spam):
  File "./test.py", line 14, in Eggs
    @foo.setter
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

To make this work as desired, I need to re-define `Eggs.foo`:

```
class Eggs(Spam):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return super().foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo):
        self.bar = ' '.join(['Egg\'s foo:', foo])
```

Is there a way to avoid this re-definition of the property?
Since this is very annoying if you have lots of getters and setters like this in several sub-classes like I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the class name as well:

```
class Eggs(Spam):
    @Spam.foo.setter
    def foo(self, foo):
        self.bar = ' '.join(['Egg\'s foo:', foo])
```

Comment: Just wondering if this can be done without hardcoding the parent class name.

Comment: Indeed, this solves the problem. But I still do not understand why the ```Eggs.foo``` property is not being inherited from the super class.
I also second the question of @georg .

Comment: @RichardNeumann You cannot use a plain foo.setter because `foo` doesn't exist while the class properties are created. I will try to post a solution using metaclass(is it's possible) as soon as I get some free time.

Comment: @georg I thought of implementing a custom decorator that hunts down inheritance and does what the hard-coding does... but it may lack precision in some cases, precisely in multiple inheritance.

Comment: If I do this (use @Spam.foo.setter), is it possible to call super().foo setter somehow? I couldn't find a way to do this so far.

Comment: @zacharmarz `super(Eggs, type(self)).foo.fset(self, val)` ?